# Graphing a complicated equation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How would I go about graphing the following equation:

```
y(t)=\left(-1+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\right)
     e^{(\frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2})t}+-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}
     e^{(\frac{-3 - \sqrt{5}}{2})t}+1}
```

I had written this, but it did not work:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-1:1,
    samples=101,
    smooth,
    no markers,
    ]
    \addplot (-1+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}})e^{(\frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2})t}+-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}e^{(\frac{-3 - \sqrt{5}}{2})t}+1;

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use a/b, not \frac{a}{b}.  Use sqrt(), not \sqrt{} etc.   for defining functions in addplot...

Comment: In addition to what @cis is saying you need to specify multiplications by `*` and either define `t` to be plot variable or use `x` instead. `    \addplot{(-1+(sqrt(5)-1)/(2*sqrt(5)))*exp((-3 + sqrt(5))*x/2)
  -((5-sqrt(5))/10)*exp((-3 - sqrt(5)/2)*x)+1};` works.

Answer (score 4):

You need to distinguish between the macros that are used to typeset an equation and pgf functions that can be used when parsing expressions. This includes, as mentioned by @cis, replacing `\frac{...}{...}` by `(...)/(...)` and `\sqrt{...}` by `sqrt(...)` and a lot more, e.g. `e^{...}` goes to `exp(...)`. While it is common to suppress multiplication signs when typesetting equations, you need to resurrect them when you plot them. Also you need either to tell `pgfplots` that `t` is your plot variable (or just use `x` instead). Other than that it would be great if you could complete your document by supplying it with the preamble.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title={$y(t)=\left(-1+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2\sqrt{5}}\right)
     \mathrm{e}^{(\frac{-3 + \sqrt{5}}{2})t}-\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{10}
     \mathrm{e}^{(\frac{-3 - \sqrt{5}}{2})t}+1$},
    domain=-1:1,
    samples=101,
    smooth,
    no markers,
    xlabel=$t$,
    ylabel=$y(t)$,
    ]
    \addplot[variable=t]{(-1+(sqrt(5)-1)/(2*sqrt(5)))*exp((-3 + sqrt(5))*t/2)
     -((5-sqrt(5))/10)*exp((-3 - sqrt(5)/2)*t)+1};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]